# No agents are registered or you do not have permission to view the agents

Tags: azure-devops

After creating the new custom agent pool, if I am view that, I am seeing the message as "No agents are registered or you do not have permission to view the agents.". Can anyone tell me what kind permission is needed or do I need to any other configuration?

And I have created this pool with my username which has administrator privilege.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for my issue. Actually while running config.cmd, it ask for agent pool. I pressed enter for default. Instead of that, now I have entered the name which I created. It started working.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the message you see must as the pic shown below:

[image]

That's because you did not add any agents into this agent pool after you add a new pool. In azure Devops, agent pool is just a pool which contains several agents. And the build and release pipeline are all running in agent. So, you need to add an agent into this pool.

To add a agent into this pool, you should go New Agent-> choose relevant agent you want to download:

[image]

Follow the steps to configure your local agent. And after the agent configured successfully, you will see an agent exists under the pool and message disappeared.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I forgot to mentioned that I have followed these steps beofre post this issue. I have downloaded the ZIP (Windows) and moved to server machine (windows server 2019). I have executed the config.cmd file in command prompt by running it as administrator. And the service is running when i check that in services.msc. Still did I missed any step or did I followed any wrong steps?

Comment: @Kattesang Did you configure the agent successfully? After the last step of configure, you will see the line tell you that it is successfully now. Don’t you see that?

Comment: Yes I saw the success message.

Comment: @Kattesang But nothing changed in your customized agent pool?

Comment: Got the solution. Actually while running config.cmd, it ask for agent pool. I pressed enter for default. Instead of that, now I have entered the name which I created. It started working. Thanks Merlin liang